# Checking the number of `expects` in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

Can someone tell me if there is a way to expect a number of assertions in Jasmine? something [like this](https://github.com/UziTech/jasmine-expect-count)

I am looking for something like [this Jest function](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#expectassertionsnumber).

The reason I want this is because I have async tests and I want to be positive that all the expectations are being met.

I am using Jasmine as it is default with Angular.

Other suggestions for how to ensure all tests are running are also welcome.

Comment: why has this received so many negative votes? This seems like a very legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jasmine-expect-count](https://github.com/UziTech/jasmine-expect-count)